# angularjs web version working mobile textarea can't edit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an issue with using my app on my cell phone.

It is working on laptop browser just fine. When I try to use my phone I can't edit a textarea.

The flow is as follows:
Open modal
can't access textarea

```
              $scope.testMember = function (item) {

                $modalStack.dismissAll('cancel');

                $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: './testmail.html',
                  controller: 'TestMailCtrl',
                  resolve: {
                    emailRead: function() {
                      return item;
                    }
                  }
                });


                 <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-4 follow-info">
                  <label class="control-label">Message:<br/></label>
                    <textarea name="bodyText" id="bodyText" class="form-control" ng-maxlength="2000" cols="400" rows="10" ng-model="testBodyText"></textarea>
                </div>
```

This works fine on my laptop. Does not work on my phone.

Phil

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2280jbielick commented on 
The issue mainly boils down to the modal template having an ngClick directive on the modal window itself. I couldn't tell you why this is necessary. In the angular-foundation package, which shares almost exactly the same html for the modal template, the ng-click="close($event)" doesn't map to anything at all. It's scope holds no close property or function.

Comment: found the answer..I'm working around this in my own project by blocking touchend events from propagating past the modal form like this:

<div class="modal-body" stop-event="touchend">
With a directive like this:

  .directive('stopEvent', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.on(attr.stopEvent, function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        });
      }
    };
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working around this in my own project by blocking touchend events from propagating past the modal form like this:

```
  <div class="modal-body" stop-event="touchend">
```

With a directive like this:

```
 .directive('stopEvent', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    element.on(attr.stopEvent, function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
};
```

});